# Why is my sites CSS trying to load from old site? WORDPRESS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

As you can see the site is trying to load the CSS from the old original URL `http://www.stockportwindowinstallations.gridhosted.co.uk` instead of `http://www.stockportwindowinstallations.co.uk/`

Link: http://www.stockportwindowinstallations.co.uk/

[image: Screenshot]

Wordpress > Options is correct

wp_options is correct

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/b3bcac84943143438b147d6b265b1b67.png

shows the errors in the console of it trying to read css from the old url

Comment: Not a PHP issue. You stylesheet calls are wrong.

Comment: It isnt just the CSS its also Javascript, images etc.

Comment: Those are all client side, not a PHP issue. Note your requests all have 2 domains in them. I'd guess you appended the new URL onto the old one.

Comment: http://www.stockportwindowinstallations.gridhosted.co.uk is the original URL that I was given before I bought a domain, but I have changed both the things suggested below and it should be working now right?

Comment: Look at `href='http://www.stockportwindowinstallations.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/wp-content/themes/appointment/style.css?ver=4.5.6'` You shouldn't have 2 TLDs (or I find that pretty strange). I don't know what your domain is/was/is supposed to be but I'd start at looking the 2 `co.uk.`s.

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is related to Website Url.

Check out [WordPress - Changing The Site URL][1] and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/f3712a2bf8294122bd3754faa41129b0.png

These are the correct urls

Comment: I guess downvoting should be given for a "wrong answer", but mine was a viable option.

Answer (score -1):

Did you recently moved your website? or changed the URL? 
Login to phpmyadmin (or similar) and check your wp_options table
the first 2 items (siteurl & home) should match your new URL

Comment: how are you loading your css/js? Can you show us the code that handles your styles & scripts loading?

Comment: Not sure how to find that, its a wordpress template called appointment

Comment: Did you edit your functions.php file? If yes, can you post the relevant functions.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m4a90Net - Nothing was changed upon transferring to the new host

Comment: I think the culprit might be that the scripts.php file is throwing an error, look into your /scripts/scripts.php you get a fatal error (Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /var/sites/s/stockportwindowinstallations.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/appointment/functions/scripts/script.php on line 28)

All your css and scripts are being handled by that exact file.. try to fix the error in there.

Comment: Hi, I cant see anything wrong with this file: 

http://pastebin.com/dbtDSgun

Can you spot anything? I really appreciate the help